# How to write an inline snippet to insert a text input that reveals a button tif the correct text is entered in the input field?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide a button (or disable it) until the user has entered the right text in an input field. I am OK with solutions that have the "password" visible in the source as it's not a problem for this use case, but my constraints are that the entire solution needs to be compatible with my CMS carrd.co (documentation on in-line code blocks here: https://carrd.co/docs/building/embedding-custom-code)

To the best of my understanding (not a dev) some of the existing solutions I found on Stack Exchange don't work in this context (I tried a few, it's possible I didn't place the  tags correctly or missed some similar basic step, but as it stands I am stuck)

Some similar questions: [Enable a button on entering text in input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35199701/enable-a-button-on-entering-text-in-input-field) and
[Show / hide html based on prop type on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442507/show-hide-html-based-on-prop-type-on-input)

Comment: can you show us what you have tried till now?

Comment: _"Some similar questions:"_ - those appear to be quite specific to the frameworks used in each of those cases, angular resp. vue.js. Unless your CMS uses either of those, you probably need a more generic solution. A change or input handler added for the input field, and if the current value matches the one you are looking for, then show or enable the previously hidden/disabled button ... That's not actually rocket science, but we really have no relevant details whatsoever here so far (like how could those elements be selected to begin with - IDs, classes, ...?)